# Excel date convertion in JavaScript gives one day less

Tags: javascript, excel, excel-dates

I was trying convert the excel date "`47308`" to date object in javascript using the below method

```
function getExcelDateAsDate(excelDate, format){
    var unixTimestamp = (excelDate-25569)*86400000 ;
    return new Date(unixTimestamp);
}
```

however,I am getting the value as "`Sun Jul 08 2029 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`" in javscript instead of "`Mon Jul 09 2029`".

Any idea why am I getting 1 day less in javascript.

Comment: this is likely due to the timezone offset not being considered properly when doing the convertion

Comment: The two dates you've shown are the same date.  Jul-08 20:00 +4hours = Jul-09 0:00 + 0hours.

Comment: @ChrisG, yes. I tried from different time zone and it seems working. However, it will be great if i could make it immune to timezone